# How to properly define data models in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, data-modeling

I am teaching a class on TypeScript basics and I realized something that is really confusing to students and also to me. If I define my TypeScript data model like this

```
interface Person {
  name: string;
  age: number;
}

interface Teacher extends Person {
  subject: string;
}

interface Student extends Person {
  grade: number;
}
```

I cannot actually do the following which my students expect to by possible from experience with other languages such as Java, C# etc.

```
const people: Person[] = [
  { name: "Alice", age: 30, grade: 100 },
  { name: "Bob", age: 25, subject: "Math"},
];
```

I would argue, ther `extends` does not create a proper subtype/supertype relationship. It only copies properties from one type to onether. To make this work you need to do this:

```
interface BasePerson {
  name: string;
  age: number;
}

interface Teacher extends Person {
  subject: string;
}

interface Student extends Person {
  grade: number;
}

type Person = Teacher | Student;
```

But I am unable to explain to my students why `extends` works this way. And also, I am not even sure that my solution is the prefered one. Am I getting it completely wrong and there is a better way to structure data models?

Comment: I don't have time to get into the nitty gritty here but, as you are a teacher, it is absolutely essential that you emphatically ingrain into your students that their intuitions from languages like C#, Java, Kotlin, must be discarded entirely!  Not only is the type system completely different, it models the JS runtime which also doesn't behave anything like those languages. In other words, they mustn't depend on analogies at the type system level, especially based on keywords. You must teach JavaScript in tandem with TS and actually warn your students that they're intuition is likely suspect